# app works on simulator but not on android

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

I tested my app on android phone and it stopped in the middle of playing, it stops when it is about to change scene.(It works on the simulator.) I debugged it using the instructions by: http://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/07/09/tutorial-basic-debugging/

This is what it gave me in the cmd.

```
beginning of /dev/log/main
.....
I/Corona <24200>:cannonCharge   
I/Corona <24200>:shot
I/Corona <24200>:event listener   
I/Corona <24200>:Ball is colliding   
I/Corona <24200>:Before changing scene
```

Then it just stops here and then a popout on my phone screen says balloon game has stopped.  This part of the code i think went wrong.

```
   if (event.other == balloons[1])  then
     scene.updateScore()
     print('Ball is colliding')
     balloon1:removeSelf()
     balloon1 = nil
     balloonText1:removeSelf() 
     balloonText1 = nil
     audio.play(pop)
     print('Before changing scene')
     storyboard.gotoScene("correct1", "fade", 1000)
   end
   ...
```

I thought maybe its the file name because I know android is case sensitive so i changed all the file names to lower case. The images showed so I don't think theres any problem with them but also checked just in case. Up to now I don't know what else I could try, any suggestions?
And I tried removing some codes and found out everything works up until storyboard.gotoScene("correct1", "fade", 1000). I can't see any problems with it and even tried to link it to a different scene "results" which is also the same result.

Comment: Not enough details are provided to answer this. Have you tried to remove this block?

Comment: You keep asking tons of questions without doing hardly any of the work yourself.  You need to do some debugging.  Start removing certain lines and seeing if it still runs.  Hook your device up to your computer and get the `adb logcat` to run so you can see the error messages from your phone.  You need to put more effort into your own debugging.

Comment: I used adb logcat Corona:v *:s instead because adb logcat doesn't stop  showing  codes, it shows a 100 blocks in couple of seconds and i have no way of knowing which one is the one that relates to my app. I deleted a few lines and tested it again, everything works perfectly till storyboard.gotoScene("correct1", "fade", 1000). I tested it again by replacing the "correct1" with "results" scene which also doesn't work.

Comment: When using the regular logcat I have to let it run for a couple of seconds for it to get to the end of the log.  Once at the end you shouldn't see as many entries in the log (usually only as you do stuff in the app).  Then once to the spot where the bug happens, let it happen and then `Ctrl+C` to stop the logcat and see if there are errors.

Answer (score 1):

When faced with such situation, one technique that works well is to add many print statements in the code so that you can find the last line that gets executed. Here you have a print statement before the scene goto but unless you have one after, there is no way of knowing if that is where it hangs.

Once you have done that, you start removing code (comment out) until the problem disappears. The problem is not necessarily the line that hangs; it could easily be in the lines prior, even something done at initialization. So you comment out big blocks of code but leave the structure (like all the scene gotos), just comment out things like audio, buttons (except the one required to trigger the goto), etc. When a code removal makes problem disappear, you at least have something to look at (wrong config values, etc).

Answer (score 0):

The code above is fine and i cant find any mistake, so upload the other part of the code so that i can check it. General advice is make sure that your are using the correct file names and the scene names .